# How to get the sequence of members of nested lists?

Tags: syntax

I work with Mathematica 7.

I have a list of lists, e.g.: `l = { {{1,2}}, {{1,2},{2,3}} }`.

What is the Mathematica command to get the sequence (not the list) of members of a nested list? The result for my example: `{{1,2}}, {{1,2},{2,3}}`.

What is the Mathematica command to map a Mathematica command to the sequence (not to the list) of members of a nested list? The result for my example: `f[{{1,2}},{{1,2},{2,3}}]` or `{f[{1,2}],f[{1,2},{2,3}]}`.

Comment: `Map[f, l, {1}]` or simply `f /@ l`

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{{1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}};
```

Use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (@@)

```
Sequence @@ list

(* Sequence[{{1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}] *)

f[Sequence @@ list]

(* f[{{1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}] *)
```

Or, more directly

```
f @@ list

(* f[{{1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}] *)
```

Comment: Isn OP asking for something more like `Sequence @@ ( f/@list )` in the second case?

Comment: @jjc385 - both results are identical and the same as the requested result of `f[{{1,2}},{{1,2},{2,3}}]`

Comment: It looks like OP edited the question.  Nevermind!

Comment: I would expect a Mathematica function that gives the members of a list. In Maple: op(l) or op(n,l)